# RCP/RAP: Link in SWT/JFace-TableViewer-Cell

Tags: hyperlink, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface, eclipse-rap

Does anyone know a possibility to place a link in a JFace-TableViewer-Cell? I just need something that fires an event, when it is clicked on. Something that looks like a hyperlink would be perfect. The (big) problem is, that it should work not only under RCP but also under RAP.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do this for RAP, but for RCP have a look at the answer for [How to add Hyperlink in SWT Table`s column?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6981638/796559).

Unfortunately, the graphical context is not supported with RAP (AFAIK...)...

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy and can be done with something called Markup (https://www.eclipse.org/rap/developers-guide/devguide.php?topic=markup.html&version=3.23): in getText() of ColumnLabelProvider you could provide html part for example getText() result for link could look like this:

```
return "<a href='http://www.eclipse.org/rap' target='_blank'>RAP</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `TreeViewerColumn.setEditingSupport` and override the `ColumnViewer` class. In that way, you could have your own custom control after you click on a cell (in edition mode).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).