# How to add Hyperlink in SWT Table`s column?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

How to add Hyperlink in SWT Table column ?
I`m using org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table class.

Is there any way to do this without using TableViewer, JFace ?

I tried this way but not working correctly (not showing hyperlinks).

```
for(int i=2; i<4; i++){ 
Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink(table, SWT.WRAP); 
link.setText(temp[i]); 
link.setUnderlined(true);
TableEditor editor = new TableEditor(table); 
editor.setEditor(link, tableItem[index-1], i); //set hyperlinks in column i
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is certainly possible. To do this you have to implement `SWT.ItemPaint` (and possibly also `SWT.ItemErase` and `SWT.ItemMeassure`).

It is easier with `TableView` though if you use the correct `LabelProvider`...

Answer (score 4):

Below is one way to draw the hyperlink using TableView with a LabelProvider, as mentioned in Tonny Madsen's answer.

The code below just *paints* the hyperlink.

```
    TableViewerColumn column = ...
    column.setLabelProvider( new MyHyperlinkLabelProvider( tableViewerFiles.getTable() ));

private final class MyHyperlinkLabelProvider extends StyledCellLabelProvider {
    MyHyperlink m_control;

    private MyHyperlinkLabelProvider( Composite parent ) {
        m_control = new MyHyperlink( parent, SWT.WRAP );
    }

    @Override 
    protected void paint( Event event, Object element ) {
        String sValue = ... [Get cell value from row element]
        m_control.setText( sValue );

        GC gc = event.gc;
        Rectangle cellRect = new Rectangle( event.x, event.y, event.width, event.height );
        cellRect.width = 4000;

        m_control.paintText( gc, cellRect);
    }
}

private class MyHyperlink extends Hyperlink {
    public MyHyperlink(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, style);
        this.setUnderlined(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintText(GC gc, Rectangle bounds) {
        super.paintText(gc, bounds);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the size of the editor:

```
editor.grabHorizontal = true;
//or
editor.minimumWidth = 50;
```