# set cursor icon when mousemove on swt table coloumn

Tags: java, swt

I want to add hyperlink on table item in swt but I can not find any  method for it.Now  I want to set cursor icon to hand icon when the cursor move on that particular item column..
so that particular item feel like a hyperlink.tell me any suggestion or method of this..

```
public void drawTable(String[] str) {
    if (str != null) {
        TableItem it1 = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
        int i = str.length;
        String[] tmp = new String[i];
        tmp[0] = str[0];
        tmp[1] = str[1];
        int k = i - 1;
        for (int j = 2; j < i; j++, k--) {
            tmp[j] = str[k];
        }
        it1.setText(tmp);
        for (i = 2; i < str.length; i++) {
            it1.setForeground(i, display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add hyperlink to table cell, you'll have to write your own `StyledCellLabelProvider` see [StyledCellLabelProvider snippet](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFaceSnippets#Snippet049StyledCellLabelProvider) for details. It's also similar question to [How to add Hyperlink in SWT Table`s column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981638/how-to-add-hyperlink-in-swt-tables-column).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`table.addMouseMoveListener`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/events/MouseMoveListener.html).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but i do not want to make whole table column as hyperlink.I just want table item at column 3 and 4 as hyperlink.I want to addlistener on that tableitem .

Comment: @Ashish Panery: Check which item and column are under the mouse in your listener.

Answer (score 0):

I found that there is no option for making item data as hyperlink. So i just colored my item data and check the coordinate of the point where user click and check that it is in the column or not, which i use as column for hyperlink and do my operation...

Thanks to all.
code will paste soon.